# Unable to build an android gradle project - for a cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am unable to build a gradle project, even if I edit the gradle property, I get the following error:

```
Error:(22, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'android']
   > Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\salangar\angular-cordova-tickrv0.1\platforms\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Simple way will be right click on project ->open module settings -> on left click project(below sdk location) ->change  gradle version to 2.10.. This will work if you are not manually changing the version anywhere in gradle..

Comment: @sunil Cordova will overwrite this settings on the next build. You have to tell cordova to use gradle 2.10. I'm still searching for a solution

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was also getting the same error and modifying the
$(your app path)/platform/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

didn't help as it was getting overridden every time i ran cordova build android to 2.2.1

I finally changed the gradleBuilder.js file under $(your app path)/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders folder.

Search for distributionUrl and change it 2.10.

This triggered download of gradle-2.10 and compilation went through. At least it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you soo much! It was so hard to find this fix

Answer (score 7):

Instead of manipulating build.js file, the easiet approach would be as follows:

> 1) Download required gradle version and save it local folder.
>
> 2) In command prompt execute the following command:
>       export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=file:///local/path/to/folder/where/gradle/zip/is/saved/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
>
> 3) Execute the following command: cordova run android

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the issue here. Android Studio asks to upgrade gradle. Don't do that ! I've made a bug report. The version has to keep being updated in Android Studio after each rebuild on the command line.

`File -> Project Structure -> Project.` Need to keep changing it to 2.10. There is not one fix for this yet that I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

it will always generate same file every times you run build, so the way to handle it find the generator .. in my case App Location> platform > android> cordova >lib> builders> Gradlebuilder.js and find this ..

```
var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'https\\: '
```

after edit it, every time code generate will create new distribution url you make.

Answer (score 0):

Edit $(your app path)/platform/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:
find:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Change to:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Comment: But it will change back after building.

Comment: It does change back... anyone?

Comment: Edit gradle-wrapper.properties. And build with:`platforms/android/gradlew build`  If any lint error , edit `CordovaLib/build.gradle` add `  lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }` in android object.

Answer (score 0):

I use sencha touch 2.4.2 and cordova 5.4.1.

I had the same error because the Sencha-Cmd:

`sencha app build native` always rewrite the file: `$(your app path)/cordova/platform/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

And reset the variable distributionUrl to the old bad value: `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip`

To solve that, i have changed the variable `distributionUrl`, directly in the file: `$(your app path)/cordova/platforms/android/cordova/lib/build.js`
at line 346 change build.js:

```
// New good value
var distributionUrl = 'distributionUrl=http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip';
// Old bad value
// var distributionUrl = 'distributionUrl=http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';
```

And that permanently solve the problem and i can now have a successful native build for Android ;)