# Adding Cordova plugin to existing Android Project

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, cordova-plugins

How can I add a Cordova plugin to an Android Cordova project which I am already working on in Android Studio?

If I add from command line it gives an error that Cordova project cannot be built.

Comment: What plugin you're adding ?

Comment: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/

Comment: did you tried adding platform again after installing plugin ?

Comment: No, when I try to add the plugin, the command itself initiates the build command too.

Comment: What is error log ?

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/cdac/App/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/cdac/App/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-3.3-all.zip

Comment: seems to be there is problem with SDK. Try to update to latest and try again.

Comment: @Sumit you gotta upgarde your gradle. Check out this links - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565993/unable-to-build-an-android-gradle-project-for-a-cordova-project/37431572#37431572  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367247/how-to-sync-gradle-with-apache-cordova/37371948#37371948